# Cascading combo boxes with Angular JS and ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, angularjs

Using ASP.NET (not MVC) and Angular.js,

I am new to Angular so need some help

I have 4 selects that are linked together using angular.js,

The only problem is that i want all of them to be populated when the page loads,

Right now, only the main select (the one that controls all the rest) is loaded and when i select an item, all the rest are populated accordingly.

**My Js is as follows:**

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('ProfessionalsComboCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.professionalExpertiseTypes = [];
        $scope.subExpertise = [];
        $scope.professionalAreaTypes = [];
        $scope.professionals = [];
        $scope.professionals.ProfessionalExpertises = [];

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "Service/ProfessionalsService.asmx/GetProfessionals",
            data: {},
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            }
        }).success(function (data) {

            $scope.professionals = JSON.parse(data.d);
        });


        $scope.GetSubExpertise = function (pId) {

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url:    "Service/ProfessionalsService.asmx/GetProfessionalsExpertise",
                data: { parentId: pId },
                dataType: "json",
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                }
            }).success(function (data) {

                $scope.subExpertise = JSON.parse(data.d);
            });
        }
```

**My HTML is as follows:**

```
<select ng-model="item.Id" ng-options="item.Id as item.Name for item in p.ProfessionalExpertises" ng-change="GetSubExpertise(item.Id)">
    </select>
<select ng-model="subItem.Id" ng-options="subItem.Id as subItem.Name for subItem in subExpertise">
    </select>
<select ng-model="areaTypes.AreaId" ng-options="areaTypes.AreaId as areaTypes.AreaName for areaTypes in p.ProfessionalAreas">
                </select>
                <select ng-model="p" ng-options="prof.Name for prof in professionals">
                </select>
```

The JSON "Professionals" object structure for example:

```
"[{"Id":2056,"Name":"Rick",
"ProfessionalExpertises":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Teachers","ParentId":0,"HasChildren":false},
{"Id":2,"Name":"Accountant","ParentId":0,"HasChildren":false},{"Id":4,"Name":"Graphologist","ParentId":0,"HasChildren":false}],
"ProfessionalAreas":[{"AreaId":1,"AreaName":"North","Key":1,"IsSaved":true},{"AreaId":3,"AreaName":"South","Key":3,"IsSaved":true},{"AreaId":5,"AreaName":"Center","Key":5,"IsSaved":true}]},{"Id":2085,"Name":"DannyBoy",
"ProfessionalExpertises":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Doctors","ParentId":3,"HasChildren":false},
{"Id":2,"Name":"Accountant","ParentId":0,"HasChildren":false},{"Id":4,"Name":"Grafologist","ParentId":0,"HasChildren":false}],
"ProfessionalAreas":[{"AreaId":1,"AreaName":"North","Key":1,"IsSaved":true}"
```

I got it to work so that the selects are cascading but i want all of them to fill when the page loads and not just "professionals"....

Not sure how to do that...since all the other selects are populating from the main one...i need a seperate object for each of them (?) but then i would ruin the cascade...

Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add calls to data function filling other selected inside first function:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "Service/ProfessionalsService.asmx/GetProfessionals",
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }
}).success(function (data) {
    $scope.professionals = JSON.parse(data.d);
    GetSubExpertise($scope.professionals[0].Id);
    $scope.professionalAreaTypes = $scope.professionals[0].ProfessionalAreas;
});
```

and change your view to:

```
<select ng-model="areaTypes.AreaId" ng-options="areaTypes.AreaId as areaTypes.AreaName for areaTypes in professionalAreaTypes">
                </select>
```

Of course add appropriate empty checks and similar stuff, but I think this example shows the idea.

Comment: Thanks ! what about p.ProfessionalAreas, since it is populated by the same json data as professionals, how can i populate it independantly on page load ?

Comment: Yes but then i loose the linkage between them..and it only fills the area for the first professional

Comment: @RoyLivne Sorry, but your intentions are not clear to me... What for you mean to populate ProfessionalAreas independantly?

Comment: The "ProfessionalsArea" combo depends on "professionals" and vice verca, but i also want it to fill with all the values when the page loads, regardless if i chose a value in the "professional" combo. But because they are connected i dont have a choice....so i was wondering if there is a way to fill all these combos on page load and also keep them linked...hope this is more clear